# Iframe creates extra space below

Tags: html, css, iframe

Why does an iframe add extra space under its element? Look at this weird behavior:

```css
.border {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.border iframe {
    border: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.border .lower {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
  <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

How to work around?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to your Iframe style like so:

```
.border iframe {
    border: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display:block; /* Add this */
}
```

Iframe is an Inline Frame, meaning that it is an inline element, which like the img tag, can have issues with whitespace. Setting `display:block;` on it turns the Iframe into a block element (like a div), which will remove the whitespace issue.

Comment: Well that was a fun three hours.

Comment: For those coming across this now, the iFrame must have a fixed width, `width: 100%` does not work to close the gap within the iFrame and the `<body>`.

Comment: @BrandonFranklin is there a way to fix this while maintaining a dynamic 100% width?

Answer (score 11):

`iframe` is an inline element. This takes whitespace in your HTML into account. `display:inline-block` is notorious for being difficult.

Add `display:block;` to the CSS for your iframe.

Answer (score 6):

The `iframe` element is an inline element. One way of fixing the spacing issue is adding `display: block`, but you can also fix it by simply adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `iframe` element.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the iframe was correctly in a block and size width and height were both corrects.
I applied this to the **container of my iframe** and it worked :

```
.iframe-container{
line-height:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just add "style="display:block"" in the iframe params.

for example

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="display:block" 
    src="https://www.url.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the `<iframe>` inside a container with `display: flex` and removing the border from the `<iframe>` with `border: 0` also seems to work:

```css
/* doesn't work */
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.container iframe {
  height: 100%;
}

/* works */
.container-flex {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-flex iframe {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7X8II6J-6mU"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="container-flex">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7X8II6J-6mU"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Wordpress site. None of the solutions above worked. When I inspected the iframe in Chrome Developer Tools, I saw that it was wrapped in a paragraph (p). I removed it, problem was solved.

So, if you will embed a Google Map in a Wordpress site, don't forget that WP adds paragraphs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers worked for me when designing for just mobile or just desktop, but when the padding-bottom would have been different based on the size of the screen, it did not work.

What does work is using [Viewport Height](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).

I added these to my CSS and it resolved the issue in all resolutions.

```
.resp-iframe 
{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the frame in div and make div same height of an iframe

like this:

```
<div style="height: 370px;">
    <iframe height="370"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually solved my issue for a paypal button iframe in woocommerce/wordpress. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## 02 2022 (Bootstrap 5.1)

I thought I will contribute to this question by using CSS and also with Bootstrap 5.1
I will be using Google Map as an example.

### on iFrame

**CSS method**: you can use `display:block` in the `style` attribute

```
                                                                   ↓                             
                                                              -------------                      
<iframe src="SOURCE" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;display:block" allowfullscreen=""
loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

**Bootstrap method**: use `d-block` class

```
                                                                      ↓                             
                                                                ------------- 
<iframe src="SOURCE" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" class="d-block" allowfullscreen=""
loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

### on iFrame Parent

**CSS method**: If you wrap with a `div` you can use `line-height:0` to your parent element.

```
                 ↓
            -------------
<div style="line-height:0">
  <iframe src="SOURCE" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Boostrap method**: Speaking of line-height, bootstrap has four line-height classes `lh-1`, `lh-sm`, `lh-base`, `lh-lg` they are good for text but unfortunately they don't work on iframe. Also adding `d-block` to the parent doesn't work instead, you can use `d-block` on the iframe just like CSS.

```
<div>
                                                                             ↓
                                                                       -------------
    <iframe src="SOURCE_HERE" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;display:block" allowfullscreen="" 
loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>
```

### Fixed Parent height

If your parent height is fixed then you can set the iframe to `height="100%"` which will expand the iframe height to match with your parent

```
.parent{
    height: 500px;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
                                                   ↓
                                                 ------
    <iframe src="SOURCE_HERE" width="600" height="100%" style="border:0" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>
```

### No access to the iframe element

If you do not have control of your iframe element then you can set your parent height to match with the iframe height.

```
.parent{
    height: 450px;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
                                                   ↓
                                                 -----
    <iframe src="SOURCE_HERE" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;display:block" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pls add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` in the **.boder** style.

so the style will look like this:

```css
.border {
  background: #e30606;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.border iframe {
  border: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.border .lower {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
  <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for my app, was adding `overflow-y: hidden;` to the html of the iframe.

Answer (score -2):

here is another answer please check it ...

```
.border iframe {
border: none;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
opacity: 0.8;
}
```