# Column Flex,Child iframe 100% height,the parent scroll is shown

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

in the div have height 100% iframe,the parent shown Y scroll.why it overflow?

```css
.root{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}
iframe {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column root">
  <div style="background:yellow">
  Head
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
    <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.portotheme.com/"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

the iframe set to height:100%.why the parent show scroll?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sonce/z8hL9x54/3/).

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` is an inline element, which sometimes creates spacing issues. Adding `display: block;` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)) to the `iframe` fixes these problems.

See also: [Iframe creates extra space below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025319/iframe-creates-extra-space-below)

```css
.root {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column root">
  <div style="background:yellow">
  Head
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.portotheme.com"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to **[`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)** property to **root** class. That is, `overflow-y: hidden;`

```
.root{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

changes in HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column root">
  <div style="background:yellow">
  Head
  </div>
  <div class="h-100">
    <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.portotheme.com/"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [`Codepen demo`](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/VwaQRpj)

### [`JSFiddle demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayeesac/63cjahwf/)